# Reactjs AXIOS Put request

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a front end user that I want to change from backend. So I made a AXIOS query, but it doesn’t work.

```
async updateUtilisateur(user) {
    const headers = {
        'authorization': localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    }

    const {id} = user.id;
    return await axios.put('/secure/utilisateur/${id}', 
        user,{headers}
    );
},
```

In my backend log :
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/secure/utilisateur/${id}'; against '/gestion-promotions/secure/**'

2018-12-19 22:21:19.018  WARN 1432 --- [io-8080-exec-14] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${id}"]

id is a PathVariable in my request

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong type of quotation marks on this line:

```
return await axios.put('/secure/utilisateur/${id}',
```

you are using ''(single quotation marks) instead of ``(backticks) 
This is causing that your variable `id` is not correctly interpolated, then you are sending the string `${id}` to the backend.

To solve this you could use backticks:

```
return await axios.put(`/secure/utilisateur/${id}`,
```

or:

```
return await axios.put('/secure/utilisateur/' + id,
```

more info on backticks in javascript: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: How to send an integer directly to the backend from the front

Comment: You are doing it right, if you use a put you should send the id in the url, just convert the string to int in the backend before using it with: `Integer.parseInt(id)`

Comment: Apparently not, since you are telling me to convert my String to integer backend. That means that I receive a Stnrig and not a integer. I want to receive it directly.

Comment: I mean, the `PUT` call is correct, but you will not receive an `Integer` because you are converting it before sending it to be part of the url. 
The url is a long string and then the backend is getting the whole url string and extracting the id, if you want to send the id as integer you could send it in the body of the call, but that is not the standard way to do it.

Comment: If I do it like this, that is, by putting the id on the request, it works. return await axios.put('/secure/utilisateur/1', user,{headers}

Comment: Ohh I found your problem you are using the wrong type of quotation marks you should use backticks, as of now you are sending the string ${Id}, I will edit my answer in 30 minutes

Comment: What is the keyboard key to do the `

Comment: It depends on your keyboard, I can't tell you, please approve the answer if your problem was solved